# php get string from remote page

Tags: php, string

I'm creating a mobile payment processing script for my site, and to validate the payment I have to grab a string from the providers site.

The string will be either "Valid" or "Invalid"

How can I pull this string from my own site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for a particular string in the HTML from a remote page based on the URL, you can use the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://some.url.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (strstr($output, "Valid")) {
    // The payment is valid
}
else {
    // The payment is invalid
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

There's many methods, you can use [`file_get_contents( 'http://...')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or open [`socket`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) directly.

I'd go with curl, It'll give you best control with minimum amount of code.